# xpath query for FF/Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, xpath

I have a query that works fine in IE, but I can't seem to get it to run correctly in FF or Chrome.

```
...
<calendars>
<totalDates>2</totalDates>
<date>
    <dayDate>2013-12-03</dayDate>
    <intervals>
        <intervalName>AM</intervalName>
        <intervalName>PM</intervalName>
    </intervals>
</date>
<date>
    <dayDate>2013-12-04</dayDate>
    <intervals>
        <intervalName>AM</intervalName>
        <intervalName>PM</intervalName>
    </intervals>
</date>
</calendars>
...
```

To get the intervalName nodes in IE for "2013-12-04" I use:

```
intervalNodes = resp.documentElement.selectNodes("/calendars/date[dayDate='2013-12-04']/intervals/intervalName");
```

How do I get the intervalName nodes in FF/Chrome?

Thanks for the help,
Scott.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-XPath/xpath.html#XPathEvaluator e.g.

```
  var result = resp.evaluate("/calendars/date[dayDate='2013-12-04']/intervals/intervalName", resp, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);
  var node;
  while ((node = result.iterateNext()) != null)
  {
    var name = node.textContent;  
  }
```

Comment: Hi Martin, When I run the code I get: result:    XPathResult
booleanValue: [Exception: TypeError]
invalidIteratorState: false
numberValue: [Exception: TypeError]
resultType: 5
singleNodeValue: [Exception: TypeError]
snapshotLength: [Exception: TypeError]
stringValue: [Exception: TypeError]    Any ideas?

Comment: Which code have you run, just the `evaluate` call? Or the evaluate plus the while loop I posted? `selectNodes` gives you a `NodeList` which works pretty much like an array but the `evaluate` returns an `XPathResult` and for that you need to apply code like the `while` loop I posted, inside you can then access the value of each selected element as shown.

Comment: I ran the whole thing including the while loop. Nothing was returned so the 'var name' code is never entered. Could there be an issue with the xpath?

Comment: Unless the `...` preceding and trailing the `calendars` element mean there are other elements containing the `calendars` element or unless there are namespaces involved I don't see why the XPath expression should fail. If the snippet is contained in other elements then try using `//calendars/date[dayDate='2013-12-04']/intervals/intervalName`.

Comment: That was it. There are other elements above 'calendars', but I was using the whole xpath as I was in IE from the root down. However, if I code it with just the '//' in front of calendars as you showed above it works. Thanks for the help with this.